# Executing a command after navigating to a page (ReactiveUI, UWP)

Tags: uwp, reactiveui

I am trying to execute a `ReactiveCommand` after I get `NavigationEventArgs` from the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` of `Page`.

My first attempt was to use event observables, however there is no event for NavigateTo.

My second attempt is shared below. It seems that `WhenActivated` is getting called after `OnNavigatedTo`. By that time the OnNavigated is already called and hence the `navigated` don't miss the opportunity to listen the the event.

```
public sealed partial class ShareTargetPage : Page, IViewFor<ShareTargetViewModel>
{
    public event EventHandler<SharedDataEventArg> Navigated;

    private void OnNavigated(SharedDataEventArg e)
    {
        Navigated?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private IObservable<EventPattern<SharedDataEventArg>> navigated;

    public ShareTargetPage()
    {
        navigated = Observable.FromEventPattern<SharedDataEventArg>(h => Navigated += h, h => Navigated -= h);

        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ShareTargetViewModel();

        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            navigated
                .Select(x=> x.EventArgs)
                .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.ViewModel.ParseCommand)
                .DisposeWith(disposable);
        });
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var operation = (e.Parameter as ShareOperation);
        OnNavigated(new SharedDataEventArg(operation, await operation?.Data?.GetWebLinkAsync()));

    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(ShareTargetViewModel), typeof(ShareTargetPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ShareTargetViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (ShareTargetViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (ShareTargetViewModel)value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first attempt was to use event observables, however there is no event for NavigateTo.

You can create a subject and emit the `Subject.OnNext(MyOnNavigatedToEventInformation)` in the override.

> My second attempt is shared below. It seems that WhenActivated is getting called after OnNavigatedTo. By that time the OnNavigated is already called and hence the navigated don't miss the opportunity to listen the the event.

Can you use `Publish` and `Connect` to create a connected observable?  You should be able to capture the event in the observable and then emit the full sequence when you `.Connect()`.

[Publish](https://reactiveui.net/reactive-extensions/publish/observable.publish(tsource,)

[Connect](https://reactiveui.net/reactive-extensions/connect/iconnectableobservable(t).connect)

Question, is your expectation that `WhenActivated` should be called before the `OnNavigatedTo`?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that navigation happens before activation. Navigation is when the navigation stack has a entry, activation is by the UI system event.